# What is Quine’s reductionism?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, ontology, philosophy-of-physics, quine, reductionism

I am especially interested in how reductionism is related to the fact that even though science broadly comprehends a number of subjects, physics is paradigmatic.

Comment: Basically, everything is reducible to physical facts, hence physicalism in ontology, behaviorism in biology and human sciences, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine/#MetaClai). I am not sure why physics being paradigmatic is of particular note. If this is a reference to Kuhn Quine's holism was his inspiration. You may want to add more context to the post, we discourage one-liners.